# Can we get R6 class name from inside the class?

Tags: r, substitution, r6

I need to get the name of the R6 class variable from inside the class.
Can I do that?  - like in example below:

```
  Simple <- R6Class(  "Simple",
                      public = list(
                        myname = NA,
                        dt = NA, 
                        initialize = function () {
                          self$myname = substitute(self)
                        }
                      )              
  )
  mysimple <- Simple$new()  
  mysimple$myname
```

This returns `self`.
And i want this to return `mysimple`.

This would be useful for storing a class variable with `saveRDS()` and then restoring it with `saveRDS()`

Comment: Have you considered using `save(mysimple, file=)` instead? Roughly speaking, `.RData` files save name-value pairs, while `.rds` files only save values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `class(self)[1]` e.g.

```r
Simple <- R6Class(
  "Simple",
  public = list(
    getClass = function(){
      class(self)[1]
    }
  )
)

mysimple <- Simple$new()

mysimple$getClass()
```

Based on the solution in the GitHub issues: https://github.com/r-lib/R6/issues/135